# How to block pasting special characters in textbox ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-code

I am able to restrict user from typing special characters in the textbox but I need help on setting this restriction also when user is pasting special characters. How do I do this in this code of line?:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.GroupName, new { @class ="form-control", @required="required", onkeypress="return /[0-9a-zA-Z ]/i.test(event.key);"})
```

Comment: You need to write javascript to check what is in the box and remove what you don't want.

Comment: is there a way that i won't be writing it in js?

Comment: Not as far as I know.  The other way is to allow them and filter out on server side once data is posted.

Comment: JavaScript is the code that runs on the client side (if we ignore the existence of Web Assembly - so if you want to do something on the client side, ultimately you're going to have run JavaScript.

Comment: may i know how do i do this with js?

Comment: Never trust the browser to run your js, you should validate the text in your post handler anyway.

Comment: may i know how i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose that you have an Input

```
<input id="textInput" name="textInput">
```

and you have the following script to validate the copy:

```
$(function(){

   $( "#textInput" ).bind( 'paste',function()
   {
       setTimeout(function()
       { 
          //get the value of the input text
          var data= $( '#textInput' ).val() ;
          //replace the special characters to '' 
          var dataFull = data.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
          //set the new value of the input text without special characters
          $( '#textInput' ).val(dataFull);
       });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider a combination of a validation pattern and triggering validation on input

```
<input type="text" value="Test" pattern="[0-9a-zA-Z ]*" oninput="this.reportValidity()" title="Alphanumeric and space only!">
```

This doesn't prevent the user from inserting wrong characters, but it will immediately display a hint when wrong content was inserted.

Anyway, you always need to re-validate the input server-side, no matter what you do on client side.